# Div to scroll autonomously following the scroll of the main one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would love the `.npp` to scroll and follow the `#content`.
Basically every chapter inside the `#content` has a unique div and class and the class is the same of the number on the right inside the `.npp`.

If I scroll the content would it be possible for the .npp to scroll autonomously and follow the content so that when the `#content .1due` is at the top, the `.npp .1due` is at the top too?

Not sure if it's clear enough.

```css
#content{
width:70%}

.npp{
position:fixed;
right:0;
top:0;
text-align:center;
font-size:10vw;
line-height:1.5em;
overflow:auto;
height:100vh;
padding:20px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.in a{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=npp>
<div class=in>
<a href="#1uno">1</a>
<a href="#1due">2</a>
<a href="#1tre">3</a>
<a href="#1quattro">4</a>
<a href="#1cinque">5</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id=content>
<div class=poema>
<div class="canto" id="1uno" class="1uno">
<div class=inf>Inferno</div><h3>I</h3></div>
<div class=courier>
Incomincia la Commedia di Dante Alleghieri di Fiorenza, ne la quale tratta de le pene e punimenti de' vizi e de' meriti e premi de le virtù. Comincia il canto primo de la prima parte la quale si chiama Inferno, nel qual l'auttore fa proemio a tutta l'opera.<br><br></div>

Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita<br>
mi ritrovai per una selva oscura,<br>
ché la diritta via era smarrita.<br><br>

Ahi quanto a dir qual era è cosa dura<br>
esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte<br>
che nel pensier rinova la paura!<br><br>

Tant' è amara che poco è più morte;<br>
ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,<br>
dirò de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.<br><br>

Io non so ben ridir com' i' v'intrai,<br>
tant'era pien di sonno a quel punto<br>
che la verace via abbandonai.<br><br>

Ma poi ch'i' fui al piè d'un colle giunto,<br>
là dove terminava quella valle<br>
che m'avea di paura il cor compunto,<br><br>

...
</div>

<div class="canto" id="1due" class="1due">
<div class=inf>Inferno</div><h3>II</h3></div>
<div class=courier>
Incomincia la Commedia di Dante Alleghieri di Fiorenza, ne la quale tratta de le pene e punimenti de' vizi e de' meriti e premi de le virtù. Comincia il canto primo de la prima parte la quale si chiama Inferno, nel qual l'auttore fa proemio a tutta l'opera.<br><br></div>

Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita<br>
mi ritrovai per una selva oscura,<br>
ché la diritta via era smarrita.<br><br>

Ahi quanto a dir qual era è cosa dura<br>
esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte<br>
che nel pensier rinova la paura!<br><br>

Tant' è amara che poco è più morte;<br>
ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,<br>
dirò de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.<br><br>

Io non so ben ridir com' i' v'intrai,<br>
tant'era pien di sonno a quel punto<br>
che la verace via abbandonai.<br><br>

Ma poi ch'i' fui al piè d'un colle giunto,<br>
là dove terminava quella valle<br>
che m'avea di paura il cor compunto,<br><br>

...
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: so basically you want to scroll 1 up along with the first paragraph

Comment: @abhinavxeon yes and so on, so 2 with 2 and 3 with 3... Basically I want the two classes to scroll simultaneously if possible, the list is way longer.

Comment: .npp  your position is fixed  make it position:absolute;

Comment: @abhinavxeon that would make it scroll it at a different speed anyway

Answer (score 0):

```css
   

 #content{
    width:70%}

    .npp{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    
    text-align:center;
    font-size:10vw;
    line-height:1.5em;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100vh;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    .in a{display:block}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    

    <div id=content>
    <div class=poema>
    <div class="canto" id="1uno" class="1uno">
    <div class=inf>Inferno</div><h3>I</h3></div>
    <div class=courier>
<div class=npp>
    <div class=in>
    <a href="#1uno">1</a>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    Incomincia la Commedia di Dante Alleghieri di Fiorenza, ne la quale tratta de le pene e punimenti de' vizi e de' meriti e premi de le virtù. Comincia il canto primo de la prima parte la quale si chiama Inferno, nel qual l'auttore fa proemio a tutta l'opera.<br><br></div>

    Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita<br>
    mi ritrovai per una selva oscura,<br>
    ché la diritta via era smarrita.<br><br>

    Ahi quanto a dir qual era è cosa dura<br>
    esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte<br>
    che nel pensier rinova la paura!<br><br>

    Tant' è amara che poco è più morte;<br>
    ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,<br>
    dirò de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.<br><br>

    Io non so ben ridir com' i' v'intrai,<br>
    tant'era pien di sonno a quel punto<br>
    che la verace via abbandonai.<br><br>

    Ma poi ch'i' fui al piè d'un colle giunto,<br>
    là dove terminava quella valle<br>
    che m'avea di paura il cor compunto,<br><br>

    ...
    </div>

    <div class="canto" id="1due" class="1due">
    <div class=inf>Inferno</div><h3>II</h3></div>
    <div class=courier>
<div class=npp>
    <div class=in>
   <a href="#1due">2</a>

    </div>
    </div>
    Incomincia la Commedia di Dante Alleghieri di Fiorenza, ne la quale tratta de le pene e punimenti de' vizi e de' meriti e premi de le virtù. Comincia il canto primo de la prima parte la quale si chiama Inferno, nel qual l'auttore fa proemio a tutta l'opera.<br><br></div>

    Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita<br>
    mi ritrovai per una selva oscura,<br>
    ché la diritta via era smarrita.<br><br>

    Ahi quanto a dir qual era è cosa dura<br>
    esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte<br>
    che nel pensier rinova la paura!<br><br>

    Tant' è amara che poco è più morte;<br>
    ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,<br>
    dirò de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.<br><br>

    Io non so ben ridir com' i' v'intrai,<br>
    tant'era pien di sonno a quel punto<br>
    che la verace via abbandonai.<br><br>

    Ma poi ch'i' fui al piè d'un colle giunto,<br>
    là dove terminava quella valle<br>
    che m'avea di paura il cor compunto,<br><br>

    ...
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: just check once let me know  exactly what changes you want

Comment: nearly there! I just want the line-height to remain the same inside the .npp. so the solution would be for it to scroll way slower than the #content.